# Restructuring a method to fix tail recursive call not in tail position

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

Consider the following recursive power method multiplication:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
@tailrec def mult(x: Double, n:Int) : Double = {
      n match {
    case 0 => 1
    case 1 => x
    case _ if ((n & 0x01) != 0) =>  x * mult(x*x, (n-1)/2)
    case _ =>  mult(x*x, n/2)
    }
}
```

The compilation error is:

```
<console>:28: error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method mult: 
it contains a recursive call not in tail position
             y *  mult(x*x,(n-2)/2)
               ^
```

So .. given that the recursive call **is** the last entry - I presume there is an issue with the product y * (tail recursive clause) ?  How to structure this properly ?

**UPDATE**

Here is a modified version of the accepted answer - in which I was lazy and just put a third accumulator within the called method .

```
@tailrec def mult(x: Double, n:Int, accum: Double = 1.0) : Double = {
        n match {
      case 0 => accum
      case 1 => accum * x
      case _ if ((n & 0x01) != 0) =>  mult(x*x, (n-1)/2, x * accum)
      case _ =>  mult(x*x, n/2, accum)
      }
  }

mult: (x: Double, n: Int, accum: Double)Double
```

Try it out:

```
scala> mult(2, 7)
res0: Double = 128.0

scala> mult(2, 8)
res1: Double = 256.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this kind of problem. The first is to move the multiplication inside the call, possibly through the addition of a helper method:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def mult(x: Double, n: Int): Double = {
  @tailrec
  def go(x: Double, n: Int, mult: Double): Double = n match {
    case 0 => mult
    case 1 => mult * x
    case _ if (n & 0x01) != 0 => go(x * x, (n - 1) / 2, x * mult)
    case _ => go(x * x, n / 2, mult)
  }
  go(x, n, 1)
}
```

The other isn't literally an answer to your question, but it can be a more convenient approach in some cases. It's called "trampolining":

```
import scala.util.control.TailCalls._

def mult(x: Double, n: Int): Double = {
  def go(x: Double, n: Int): TailRec[Double] = n match {
    case 0 => done(1)
    case 1 => done(x)
    case _ if (n & 0x01) != 0 => tailcall(go(x * x, (n - 1) / 2).map(_ * x))
    case _ => tailcall(go(x * x, n / 2))
  }
  go(x, n).result
}
```

This doesn't require you to restructure your methods, and it's guaranteed not to blow the stack, but it does introduce some additional overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of trampolining.  btw I had a bug in my OP that you (unfortunately trusted me!) and copied. I will update in a moment here.

Comment: fixed bug in the OP. Please create two recursive calls out of my (incorrect) single one - you can see the update.

Answer (score 1):

Tail recursive calls are those calls in which last statement is the function call itself only.
i.e your last statement of your code should be `mult(x*x,(n-2)/2)` only.

You can try this.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
  @tailrec
  def mult(x: Double, n:Int,res:Double=1) : Double = {
    n match {
      case 0 => res
      case _ => mult(x,n-1,res *x)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I see your point about using an accumulator.  However your actual implementation does not do power doubling ;)

Comment: Given that your answer does in a sense answer "why" the error is occurring - but does not provide a comparable code answer, I will upvote but not award for now.

Comment: Adding a parameter muddles the API, even if you give it a default value. In many cases the approach in my answer is preferable.

Comment: I am new to scala, and still learning it.  Thanks Travis for the advice. will keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function `mult` is not tail-recursive because in the body of the function you want to do something with the result of the recursive call, namely you want to multiply it with `y`.

To make this tail-recursive you should structure the function `mult` so that it can take the value `y` as an argument to remove the multiplication after the recursive call. Here is a simple example with factorial: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TailRecursion